# How to apply sorting in ObjectDataSource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, objectdatasource

I  have asp.net grid view which is bind with ObjectDataSource1 & this ObjectdataSource1 is bind with WCF service method. I am new to asp.net.
Problem is I have to apply column wise sorting in it. But unable to do that.
Enable Sorting checkbox is not visible using C# VS2010

Comment: You should know you need more detail than this.

Comment: code have privacy I can't put it there. its a simple question of sorting.Function is calling from WCF service that why cant put sorting code inside select method

Comment: If you can't share the actual code, you still can write anonymised code triggering the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I use sorting like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  AllowSorting="true" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TelephoneNo" HeaderText=" Phone" SortExpression="TelephoneNo" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestTypeName" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="RequestTypeName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CenterName" HeaderText="Center" SortExpression="CenterName" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" TypeName="Data.RequestDB" SelectMethod="SearchRequests" SelectCountMethod="SearchRequestsCount" OnSelecting="ObjectDataSource1_Selecting" SortParameterName="sortParameter" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="telephoneNo" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

and db method:

```
public static List<Request> SearchRequests(string id, string telephoneNo, string sortParameter = null)
    {
        using (MainDataContext context = new MainDataContext())
        {
            var query = context.Requests
                .Where(t => (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) || t.ID.ToString().Contains(id)) &&
                            (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(telephoneNo) || t.TelephoneNo.ToString().Contains(telephoneNo))));

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortParameter))
                return query.OrderByDescending(t => t.ID).ThenByDescending(t => t.StatusName)
                    .ToList();

            return query.OrderBy(sortParameter)
                    .ToList();
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps you